# Super user panel in HTML - Security?

Tags: php, html, database, security

I have a website that has a database that holds typical user data, name, Paypal email etc.

I was thinking about writing a customer service panel on the website, where I can have a  "super" account where when I log in to the website, I am able to view any users information and edit it (yes the passwords are hashed and I will not be viewing or editing those).

Here is my question. lets say for example I want to ban a user by IP. I know I can go on my server and look through the DB and find the IP and then "ban" them, but it would be easier to have a account that just displayed the info.

my question is is the "super" user thing less secure in any way? of course all checks are in PHP server side code, but I would like some opinions on this.

Thanks.

**Update**

I may not of been so clear in the first part of the question. for example here is a screenshot a normal users contact page

http://s1.postimg.org/ex608kkdb/image.png

and here is a picture of the "super" users contact page

http://s1.postimg.org/qnjxpyd5r/image.png

this basically allows me to respond to people on my account without having to log into my server and go through the contact logs and etc.

this is achieved by me doing this in the PHP code

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select username from usernames where " . $number . " = '$session'");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$username =  $row[0];

if ($username == "zmhtech") {
$text = "the html to make the listbox and extra textareas";
echo $text;
}
```

My question is is this any more dangerous than not having a super user account, and just manually editing the contact files on my server?

I am planning to make another one for the DB info and the banning of accounts, but I want to make sure this is secure.

the functionality of the html(like read contact and write contact are in php as well, their is no client side code in this super user account)

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: As long as you are on ssl, and you've protected yourself from any attacks such as xss or sql injections, you should be fine.

Comment: I wouldn't use IP addresses but the user itself. IP addresses can always be spoofed/modified.

Comment: Several user management systems to this, amember is one but it's about $200 for a license for it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would build it,

is you have one login system for users ( member ) and one for admins, totally separate, separate session data etc.  then you just need a way of setting the login session data for the admin ( such as log in as ) and you don't need the password for their account.

As I mentioned in the comments there are professional products built just this way and there is definitely some utility in being able to log in as a user.

For security you should never store user information such as passwords un-ecrypted, you should also never store CC data or other information such as Social Security numbers without the proper security measures.

There is no issue then of an admin seeing their account. And as long as the admin login is as strong as their login ( hopefully more so ) then there is no issue there.  Security is only as strong as it's weakest link.  Typically that is someone giving out their credentials, via phishing, social engineering or keyloggers installed on the clients machine.  None of which you can do anything about.